# DRY selection of a subset of a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Suppose I have a dictionary `config` which, among others, has the keys `username` and `password`. I'd like to create a new dictionary consisting only of the `username` and `password` key-value pairs from `config`. One way to do this is:

```
new_dictionary = {'username': config['username'], 'password': config['password']}
```

This seems a bit verbose to me, as it contains repetitions of the words `username` and `password`. Is there a more succinct way to do this?

Comment: `dict(((k,config[k]) for k in ('username','password')))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just create `tuple` or `list` that stores names of fields that you want to be copied and iterate through every element

```
new_dictionary = {k: config[k] for k in ('username', 'password')}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could store the username/password pair in a sub dictionary (called credential)

```
config = { 'param1': 'value1', 'credential': { 'username': 'myname', 'password': 'pa22w0rd' } }
new-dictionary = config['credential']
```

You could create a credential class and pass that object around instead of a dictionary.